# JavaScript must search td for string with 'http' and convert it to link that opens in new tab when clicked

Tags: javascript, string, hyperlink

I have a table in my html that is populated dynamically from a JSON file. Once the page loads and the table is populated, some columns contain strings that are urls. I had a script that was able to search the table and assign a class to any string that started with 'http'.

I am trying to rework that script so that it will search the table (td cells), find the strings that start with 'http', convert them to hyperlinks and open the url on a new tab (_blank). But, it is not working. Can someone point out where I'm going wrong in the script below? I know there is the link() method but it is depreciated so I don't want to use it.

The table is identified by ID (#YukonTerr_FR) in the script.

Thanks!

```
var tds4 = document.querySelectorAll("#YukonTerr_FR td");
for (var i = 0; i < tds4.length; i++) {
  var str4 = tds4[i].innerText;
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  if (str4.includes("https")) {
    link.setAttribute("href", "str4");
    link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("str4"));
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the content of the `td` and append the newly created "a" element to the `td`.  Also, use the variable `str4`, not the string `"str4"`

```js
var tds4 = document.querySelectorAll("#YukonTerr_FR td");
for (var i = 0; i < tds4.length; i++) {
  var str4 = tds4[i].innerText;
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  if (str4.includes("https")) {
    tds4[i].innerText = ""; //Clear content of td
    link.setAttribute("href", str4);
    link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str4));
    tds4[i].appendChild(link); // Add the new link to td
  }
}
```

```html
<b>Before:</b>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>https://www.google.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Just a string</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>https://amazon.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<b>After:</b>
<table id="YukonTerr_FR">
  <tr>
    <td>https://www.google.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Google</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>https://amazon.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't appear to have any obvious errors, but I can't see where you're adding it back to the table.  Something like:

```
...
tds4[i].appendChild(link)
```